# ShowToastEvent throwing error when adding the component to Account Record page in my devorg

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

the below code snippet for dispatching the show toast event on successful creation of Account record using lwc

```
Thanks for the details... i have checked for case sensitivity and modified the code as below  import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
import REVENUE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.AnnualRevenue';
import INDUSTRY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Industry';
export default class AccountCreator extends LightningElement {
    @api objectApiName = ACCOUNT_OBJECT;
    fields = [NAME_FIELD, REVENUE_FIELD, INDUSTRY_FIELD];

    handleSuccess(event){
        const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
            title : "Account Created",
            message:"Record ID: "+ event.detail.Id,
            variant: "Success"

        });
    this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
    }
}

i checked the documentation and came to know that ShowToastEvent will work only in lightning experience, does that mean it won't work in the account record page?

given below is the error:

[NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.
```

Comment: did you import ShowToastEvent as noted in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-show-toast-event/documentation)?

Comment: Yes I have done that. import ShowToastEvent from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
The variant accepts only these case-sensitive values `info`, `success`, `warning`, and `error`. But in your code S in success is capital.

---

You need to enclose the `ShowToastEvent` inside `{}` because it's a named import.

The correct way is

```
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
```

Comment: I have used syntax correctly in code. It's not related to syntax. What I would like to understand is the document says showtoastevent will work with Lightning experience, but when I added the component in an account record page it is showing error.

Comment: @SoorajSudarsanakumar Then there must be some other error in your code. Please update our question and provide relevant code snippets.

Comment: i have made the changes and updated full code to the actual question, still am facing an error > [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.

Comment: @SoorajSudarsanakumar use variant in all lower case like `success`

Comment: Also corrected the event.detail.Id to event.detail.id and things are working fine now.. Thanks Much..!